# Lotus Notes Xpages, How to get "Content-Range" in api document

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I have a url `/{database}/api/data/collections/name/{name}`.

How to get all entry of view `{name}` with `getResponseHeader("Content-Range")`?

Comment: Do you want to get the *number* of all entries? Do you use LotusScript, Java or SSJS calling Domino Access Services URL?

Comment: Yes, i want get the number of all entries. I use SSJS calling Domino Access Services URL

Answer (score 1):

**SSJS**

You can get all response header fields with HttpURLConnection's method `getHeaderFields()`.

Pick your wanted header field with `get('Content-Range')`.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var url = new java.net.URL(
                "http://yourServer/yourDatabase.nsf/api/data/collections/name/All");
            var conn:java.net.HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == "200") {
                try {
                    return conn.getHeaderFields().get('Content-Range');
                } catch(e) {
                    return 'Error reading header field "Content-Range"';
                }
            } else {
                return 'Error ' + conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage();
            }
        }]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

This example XPage renders as result e.g. `items 0-9/35` and indicates that the response includes entries 0 through 9 of a total of 35 entries.

If you want to get the total number of entries only then change the line

```js
                    return conn.getHeaderFields().get('Content-Range');
```

to

```js
                    var range = conn.getHeaderFields().get('Content-Range').get(0);
                    var total = range.substr(range.indexOf('/') + 1);
                    return total;
```

This will render for the same URL `35` only.

**CSJS**

Use XMLHttpRequest's method `getResponseHeader()` on client side:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open('GET', url, false); 
xhr.send(null); 
var range = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range");
var total = range.substr(range.indexOf('/') + 1); 
return total
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: it work in server js. but i want get in client js. ~it work when i use:              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, false);
            xhr.send(null);
            var contentRanger = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range").toLowerCase();
            contentRanger=contentRanger.replace('items ','');
            contentRanger=contentRanger.split('/');
            var total=contentRanger[1]; return total

Comment: I created a Server Side JavaScript (SSJS) version as you said in your comment "I use SSJS ...". So, now we have both versions: SSJS in my answer and CSJS in your comment.

Comment: i'm sorry :D. but i don't know add code in comment :(

Comment: You can't format code in a comment. I added your code slightly modified to my answer so other developers can find both solutions easier.